# Unable to install ‘sf’ R package on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: r, package, ubuntu-16.04, rgdal, r-sf

I'm not able to install `sf` `R` package on `Ubuntu 16.04 LTS`. I tried

```
install.packages("sf")
```

as well as

```
devtools::install_github("r-spatial/sf")
```

after running

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libudunits2-dev libgdal-dev libgeos-dev libproj-dev
```

Getting the following error message:

> configure: error: gdal-config not found or not executable.
>
> ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘sf’

Wonder what is the way to install `sf`?

Comment: It works here with similar config. I have also `gdal-bin` and `libgdal20` installed. If I remember well I just installed QGIS and all necessary packages were available for `sf`

Comment: It might require the R package rgdal to also be installed. The sp package looks like it suggests it as a dependency but does not require it.

Comment: The `sf` package DESCRIPTION file has "SystemRequirements: C++11, GDAL (>= 2.0.1), GEOS (>= 3.4.0), PROJ (>= 4.8.0)" so maybe not rgdal but definitely the 4 system level packages.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This worked for me. Using

```
sudo aptitude install libgdal-dev
```

and then

```
devtools::install_github("r-spatial/sf")
```