# Can´t load eurostat and sf library

Tags: r, r-sf

So I'm trying to load eurostat and sf librarys and I get this error:

`Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘sf’:
 .onLoad falhou em loadNamespace() para 'sf', detalhes:
  chamada: get(genname, envir = envir)
  erro: object 'group_map' not found`

I loaded the rgdal package again as some other question that I saw here sugested, but I still get the same error. I also tried to begin a fresh session but no luck

Edit: the eurostat package does the same error

Comment: rgdal would have require that you install the system-resident package named GDAL. Looking at pkg:sf I see that is also required for it: "SystemRequirements: C++11, GDAL (>= 2.0.1), GEOS (>= 3.4.0), PROJ (>= 4.8.0)"

Comment: This is probably a duplicate of one or more prior questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44973639/trouble-installing-sf-due-to-gdal OR https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48628463/unable-to-install-sf-r-package-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts?r=SearchResults&s=1|123.5075 OR

Comment: http://www.gisinternals.com/release.php (for Windows.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to install ‘sf’ R package on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48628463/unable-to-install-sf-r-package-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts)

Comment: I'm sorry, from the way I had wrote it seemed like i couldn´t install the rgdal package too, but I can. Already checked and I have the GDAL version 2.2.3, so thats no where the problem is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the error was with the dplyr version that was installed, I needed the 0.8 version